$A_2 = {p \in \mathbb Q : p \leq 0} \cup {q \in \mathbb Q : q^2 \leq 2}$. Is $A_2$ open in $(\mathbb Q, d_{abs})$? Prove it
So, for the set $A_2 = \{p \in \mathbb Q : p \leq 0\} \cup \{q \in \mathbb Q : q^2 \leq 2\}$ I know that the set is open, logically because $\sqrt2$ is not in the rationals, and because of that it's open.
Now to prove it, I was going to prove it by choosing an $r < \min(x, \sqrt{2} - x)$, but I just got told that I've to prove it without using density of rationals in the reals and not to use any irrational numbers even in the choice of $r$.
So I'm a little confused on how I would go about proving this.

In MathJax braces are part of the syntax, used to group expressions, so if you want to write { and } you need to type { and }.

I made the changes @jjagmath suggested, as well as a few others. Please check that the question preserves your intent.

Hint: if you take any positive element $q \in A_2$, then $q^2 <2$ with a strict inequality since $\sqrt 2$ is not rational (I assume that you may use this fact). In other words, there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that $q^2 = 2-\varepsilon$. Can you take it from here?
